# Syntax error in onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to display a result in a textview but i get an error. The code is:

```
private class ContentView extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute()
                    {   
                        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleActivity.this);
                        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Multiplayer.it");
                        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento articoli...");
                        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        mProgressDialog.show();
                        content = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        try {
                            //String BLOG_URL_LINKS = links;
                            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(links).get();

                            String info = doc.select("div.col-1-1 article p").text();


                            System.out.println(info);
                            //info.toString();




                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // In caso di errore

                            Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
                        }
                        return null;
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
                    {   
                        articololink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
                        articololink.setText(info);
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }


                }
```

And the problem is : `info cannot be resolved to a variable`. How can i do?

Comment: articololink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content); add this into OnCreate() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info is declared and initialized in `doInbackground` is local to `doInbackground`.

So Return `info` in `doInbackground`

```
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String info=null;
      try {
          Document doc = Jsoup.connect(links).get();
          info = doc.select("div.col-1-1 article p").text();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStacktrace();     
         }
    return info;
 }
```

and then in `onPostExecute`

```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)
   {  
            super.onPostExecute(result);    
            articololink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
            articololink.setText(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Do read the topic **The 4 Steps** @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i tried but i get same error: `info cannot be resolved to a variable`